# In MS Access, I am getting unexpected result from a query of tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following tables with the following fields:

- `BeliefT (BeliefID, Beliefs, Topic, Topic2, Topic3, Topic4)`
- `ArgumentAgreeT (ReasonToAgreeID, ConclusionA, Reason to agree)` The values for these fields, come from lookups to `BeliefT.BeliefID` and `BeliefT.Beliefs`.
- `ArgumentDisagreeT (ReasonToDisagreeID, ConclusionD, Reason to Disagree)` The values for these fields, also come from lookups to `BeliefT.BeliefID` and `BeliefT.Beliefs`.

I have tried everything I can think of.
This SQL statement isn’t too bad, but it gives me weird results:

```
SELECT BeliefT.BeliefID, 
       BeliefT.Beliefs, 
       ArgumentsAgreeT.[Reason to agree], 
       ArgumentsDisagreeT.[Reason to Disagree] 
FROM (BeliefT 
      LEFT JOIN ArgumentsAgreeT ON BeliefT.BeliefID = ArgumentsAgreeT.[ConclusionA]) 
LEFT JOIN ArgumentsDisagreeT ON BeliefT.BeliefID = ArgumentsDisagreeT.[ConclusionD];
```

The above SQL statement includes the the first two things from the first table, and the `Reason to agree` and `Reason to Disagree` from the 2nd and 3rd tables. As you can tell from the SQL statement, the join type is an arrow pointing from `BeliefT.BeliefID` to both `ArgumentsAgreeT.ConclusionA` and `ArgumentsDisagreeT.ConclusionD`

The problem is that **if there is more than one reason to agree, and only one reason to disagree, that it repeats the reason to disagree for every reason to agree**. In other my `agree` table (`ArgumentAgreeT`) has 5 records. My Disagree table only has 2 records. Whenever there is a record from the `Agree` table, it duplicates the single record from my disagree table.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just in first look: the syntax of your query is wrong I mean the part in `(....)`. Using braces for `from` clause like that is invalid

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.  However, I'm not sure that MS Access is really powerful enough to do what you actually want.

Comment: re: "Also, what did you expect the result to be?"

I want to use the query to make a form. The form will have the conclusion at the top of the page, and all the reasons to agree in one column below it, and all the reasons to disagree in another column beneath it… If there are two reason to agree, it will show the two… if there are only one reason to disagree, than it will only show one…

Comment: re: "Reasons could be its own table"

Let’s say you were arguing about WWII. You could say that Germany is doing bad things is a "reason" to enter the war (the conclusion)...but you could also say that “Germany is doing bad things” is its own conclusion, with reasons to support it. If you strengthen an argument in this database, I want it to also strengthen all the conclusions based on the argument. So I think each conclusion has to have the ability to also be an argument that can support other conclusions…
Is there a way I can still do what I want? How would I structure the data?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are no [self-joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) here which are multiple references of same table with different aliases in same query.

Second, SQL queries are technically [Cartesian products](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) returning the combined set (query) from multiple sets (joined tables) according to a corresponding key. So yes, repeat records as they are paired to the other table will appear as particular combination sets. With 5 X 2 on the same BeliefID, you would naturally yield at least 10 records for every BeliefID.

Also, what did you expect the result to be? The query would not return less than the data that exists. Notice too the entire row is not a duplicate (though records repeat within a column) as each returned combination would be distinct. So even using a `DISTINCT` will not work.

Possibly, you want to run a Union query that stacks Agree and Disagree items as side by side would not return less than 10 records with table joins for each BeliefID.

```
SELECT BeliefT.BeliefID, BeliefT.Beliefs, ArgumentsAgreeT.[Reason to agree] As [Reason], 'Agree' As [Type]
FROM BeliefT LEFT JOIN ArgumentsAgreeT ON BeliefT.BeliefID = ArgumentsAgreeT.[ConclusionA]
UNION
SELECT BeliefT.BeliefID, BeliefT.Beliefs,  ArgumentsDisagreeT.[Reason to Disagree] As [Reason], 'Disagree' As Type
FROM BeliefT  LEFT JOIN ArgumentsDisagreeT ON BeliefT.BeliefID = ArgumentsDisagreeT.[ConclusionD];
```

Finally, do note your issue may not be a query problem but a table design issue. Usually when complex queries are required, data perhaps is not normalized or report requests don't follow data storage structure. The concept of [normalization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm) is to group data elements into logical groupings to avoid duplication. `Reasons` could be its own table with one-to-many link with `Beliefs`, containing a category/type field to distinguish Agree or Disagree. Doing so, you wouldn't need a union query like the above.